# A roadmap for learning standard model of particle physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, standard-model, education, lie-algebra

Assuming that a person has understanding of theory of Lie groups, Lie algebras and basic quantum mechanics, what is the simplest route to gain a basic understanding of the SM of particle physics? Are there any particular books suited for people with this background?

Comment: Special relativity, then quantum field theory and then you are ready to tackle the SM.

Answer (score 2):

A very good introduction is "Introduction to Elementary Particles" by David Griffiths.
Then, if you really want to get into the nitty gritty, jump to a text on quantum field theory, such as:

- "Quantum Field Theory" by Franz Mandl and Graham Shaw
- "Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell" by A. Zee, specially if you have any background in the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics
- "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" by Michael E. Peskin and Daniel V. Schroeder
- "A Modern Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" by Michele Maggiore

Comment: Maggiore's book is relatively new, and I think it is a superb introduction to the subject. I also think Lewis Ryder's book is excellent, but more advanced and with more detail than Maggiore.

Comment: The list I proposed is by no means exhaustive. There are other very good books out there. Ryder's is a very good one indeed :)